Why K($a_1,a_2,…,a_n$)=K[$a_1,a_2,…,a_n$] implies $a_1,a_2,…,a_n$ are algebraic on K?
I want to know how to use induction to proof K($a_1,a_2,…,a_n$)=K[$a_1,a_2,…,a_n$] implies $a_1,a_2,…,a_n$ are algebraic on K. The case n=1 is easy, but then I fail to use induction.

This is Zariski lemma, which states when $L/K$ is a field extension then $L$ is finitely generated as $K$-Algebra iff $L$ is a finite field extension as vector space over $K$. you can find it in any commutative algebra book just search for it.
$K(a_1,\dots,a_n)=K[a_1,\dots,a_n]$ is clearly finitely generated as a $K$-Algebra so $K(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is a finite extension of $K$, hence all elements are algebraic over $K$.
